# Django CMS malfunction: Site matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I've installed all apps in a project, then added a site in the sites section, and deleted example.com. Now Pages section in Django CMS 2.0 isn't working: it raises a DoesNotExist exception: `Site matching query does not exist.` at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/cms/page/

The section worked normally before I deleted the example.com site.

In settings.py I have `SITE_ID = 2` line. Still, in this call:

```
return Site.objects.get(pk=site_pk)
```

in traceback, site_pk=1.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I was having this problem after receiving an error during `syncdb`. It never occurred to me that if the syncdb is interrupted, the default site is never created. To fix this I just added a site object manually via `django-admin.py shell`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#ref-contrib-sites

The SITE_ID setting specifies the database ID of the Site object associated with that particular settings file.

So, check the django_site table and make sure you are using the correct SITE_ID for your site.

Comment: It's correct, I use Site 2, and SITE_ID is 2 as it should be.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's now working, no more showing an exception, but there's another issue.

Comment: as long as you're moving forward :-)

Answer (score 0):

after adding `sites` framework, first you need `python manage.py migrate` then you only need to add `SITE_ID=1` in `settings.py`.