# 'PollAdmin.fields' refers to field 'None' that is missing from the form

Tags: python, django, forms, field

I'm trying to make a poll with Django but I'm very new to it and when I go to the admin thing it gives this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/polls/poll/1/
'PollAdmin.fields' refers to field 'None' that is missing from the form.
```

I'm not very sure what that means but this is my admin.py file which I think is causing the error:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Poll

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fields = [
    (None,         {'fields': ['question']}),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub date']}),

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

**Edit**:

Here's my models file if that matters:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
  question = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question
  def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

class Choice(models.Model):
  poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
  choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
  votes = models.IntegerField()
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

**Edit (again)**

Now I fixed my PollAdmin class to this:

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
    (None,         {'fields': ['question']}),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
  ]
```

But it's saying:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/polls/poll/1/
Site matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 4):

Use fieldsets instead of fields:

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
    (None,         {'fields': ['question']}),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
```

Comment: Now it says this: 'PollAdmin.fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' refers to field 'pub date' that is missing from the form.

Comment: Oops sorry you need an underscore between pub and date

Comment: Did you run python manage.py syncdb after adding the admin app?

Comment: Nope. I just did and it says this. Site matching query does not exist. Sorry I'm really new to this

Comment: Sorry I haven't encountered this kind of error before, but there are many posts on stack overflow regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674615/django-cms-malfunction-site-matching-query-does-not-exist